# find minimum of a function: $X^2 + X + 1$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

How do you find the minimum value of $X^2 + X + 1$?
I know it's $3/4$ from intuition. How do you prove it?

Comment: The minimum over $\mathbb{R}$ ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For real $x,$ $$x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+1-\frac14\ge \frac34,$$ the equality occurs when $x+\frac12=0$

Alternatively, we can use [Second derivative test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html)

Answer (score 2):

We can do derivates:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2+x+1=2x+1$$
equate to zero to find stationary point (turning point) to obtain $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Check that this is indeed the minimal by computing the second derivative:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^2+x+1=2>0$$
Because the second derivative is positive, it is a minimal point.